# A natural construction of real numbers?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, real-analysis, cohomology

#### Summary

Someone claims $\mathbb{R}$ can be constructed as the following intriguing quotient, which is related to Gromov's bounded cohomology. I want to find out if it is true.

$$\frac{\bigl\{f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \mathrel| \mbox{ the set } \{f(m+n)-f(m)-f(n) \mathrel| m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\} \mbox{ is bounded}\bigr\}}{\{f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \mathrel| f \mbox{ is bounded}\} }.$$

**EDIT** See KConrad's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401441/a-natural-construction-of-real-numbers#comment1026184_401507) below. A similar construction, described in [Hermans - An elementary construction of the real
numbers, the $p$-adic numbers and the
rational adele ring](https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/bachelor/2017-2018/hermans-bscthesis.pdf), yields $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and the rational adele ring $\mathbb{A}$.

---

#### Main text

In [A'Campo - A natural construction for the real numbers](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0301015v1), a natural
construction of the real numbers is given as follows. (**EDIT**: In this post I only address the bijection and the ring structure. The correspondence is complete; for that please refer to the paper.)

**Definition (Bounded cochains)**

Define $C^{n} = C^{n}(\mathbb{Z})$ to be $\operatorname{Map}(\mathbb{Z}^{\times
n}, \mathbb{Z})$ and $C^n_b = C^{n}_b(\mathbb{Z})$ to be the
subset consisting of functions $f$ having bounded image, i.e.
$\operatorname{Card}(\operatorname{Im}(f)) < \infty$.

**Definition (Differentials)**

Define $d: C^n \to C^{n+1}$ to be such that
$$df(x_1,\dotsc,x_{n+1}) = f(x_2,\dotsc,x_{n+1}) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k} f(x_1, \dotsc, x_{k-1}, x_k+x_{k+1}, \dotsc, x_{n+1}) + (-1)^{n+1}f(x_1,\dotsc,x_n).$$

Obviously, $d(C^n_b) \subseteq C^{n+1}_b$, so $C^n_b \subseteq
d^{-1}(C^{n+1}_b)$.

**Algebraic Operations**

Clearly, $C^1$ has a ring structure, where addition is given by
point-wise addition, and multiplication is given by function
composition.

**Claim. $\mathbb{R} \simeq d^{-1}(C^2_b)/(C^1_b)$**

This claim is made in page 1 (definition of $\mathbb{R}$) and
page 6 (that $\mathbb{R}$ is the usual $\mathbb{R}$) of the
paper. An explicit map $\Phi: d^{-1}(C^2_b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is
given in page 4 as
$$\lambda \mapsto \left[\left(\frac{\lambda (n+1)}{n+1}\right)_{n \in
\mathbb{N}}\right]$$
using Cauchy sequences.

**Question** Why is $\ker(\Phi) = C^1_b$? By the
definition of the equivalence on the set of Cauchy sequences,
$\Phi(\lambda)$ represents $0 \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if

> For each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$
> such that $\frac{|\lambda(n+1)|}{(n+1)} < \epsilon$ whenever $n > N$.

However, $\lambda: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ that sends $n$ to
$\lfloor\sqrt{|n|}\rfloor$ is one such element that is not in $C^1_b$
(namely, not bounded).

**EDIT** As Anthony Quas points out [below](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401441/a-natural-construction-of-real-numbers#comment1026025_401441), such $\lambda$ isn't in the preimage of $d$. You can see this by taking $m = n \to \infty$. Still, I'm curious about a direct proof for the kernel being $C^1_b$. This is given in Anthony Quas's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/401445).

#### Related

- [Category-theoretic description of the real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/839848) (Mathematics Stack Exchange)
- Gromov's bounded cohomology, see
  [Ivanov - Notes on the bounded cohomology theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05150) and the 9th page
  of A'Campo's paper.

Comment: Who is 'someone'?  Is it A'Campo?  (Also, TeX note: $\Sigma_{k = 1}^n$ `\Sigma_{k = 1}^n` doesn't behave as an operator; prefer $\sum_{k = 1}^n$ `\sum_{k = 1}^n`.  If you want to suppress the limits placement of `\sum`, then you can write `\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^n`.)

Comment: Is your $\lambda$ in $d^{-1}(C^2_b)$? I think not.

Comment: Naive question: do you want to construct R as abelian group as a field or as a topological field?

Comment: I edited your definition of $df$, hopefully correctly, so that $df$ is (now) a function of $n+1$ variables.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_from_integers_(Eudoxus_reals)

Comment: The most useful first reference for this construction of $\mathbb{R}$ is, I think, Ross Street's "Update on the efficient reals"(http://www.maths.mq.edu.au/~street/reals.pdf). He gives some history of the construction, which has been independently discovered a few times, including by A'Campo. As I understand it, the first time it was done in print was an earlier (1985) paper of Street, cited in the link I just gave but not in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @TomLeinster Thanks for your reference! Any idea how this construction gives for general groups?

Comment: @Student You need the meaning of "bounded"

Comment: @GSM: From the wiki article cited by aorq: the quotient defined in the OP is a ring with composition and pointwise addition. This makes the quotient isomorphic to the reals as a field. I'm not sure if you can get the topology also.

Comment: It is perhaps not enough to "merely" give a "natural" bijection between the set of reals and the given set. The arithmetic and order properties should also have a "natural" definition. This can be done. Just pointing out that the correspondence is incomplete without such aspects.

Comment: @Kapil added a comment in OP accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So here is my attempt to reconstruct the construction...

Suppose $f\colon\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ satisfies $|f(m+n)-f(m)-f(n)|\le M$ as $m,n$ run over $\mathbb Z$. Then setting $m=n=2^k$, we see
$|f(2^{k+1})-2f(2^k)|\le M$, from which it follows that $f(2^k)/2^k$ is a Cauchy sequence, and so converges to some $\alpha\in\mathbb R$.

Now given $n\in (2^{k-1},2^k]$, let its binary expansion be
$n=2^{k-1}+2^{j_1}+\ldots+2^{j_r}$ (with $r< k\le \log_2 n$).
Inductively, we can show $\Big|f(n)-\big[f(2^{k-1})+\ldots +f(2^{j_r})\big]\Big|\le rM$, from which, together with the above, we can deduce that the full sequence $f(n)/n$ converges to $\alpha$.

On the other hand, given $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, if one defines $f(n)=\lfloor \alpha n\rfloor$, then it is easy to see that $f(n+m)-f(n)-f(m)$ takes values in $\{0,1\}$, so that the map is surjective.

Finally, suppose $f(n)/n\to 0$ and $|f(n+m)-f(n)-f(m)|\le M$ is bounded. We have to show that $f$ is bounded. If $|f(n_0)|\ge 2M$ for some $n_0$, then $|f(2n_0)|\ge 2|f(n_0)|-M$, from which we see inductively that $f(2^kn_0)\ge (2^k+1)M$, contradicting the assumption that $f(n)/n\to 0$.

Comment: The last paragraph is exactly what I was trying to get! It makes my day, thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

This is an extended comment.

---

A natural (in my mind) way to capture this construction is by
the following categorical interpretation.

Consider the category $\text{ACG}$ of *Abelian Coarse Groups*,
which are abelian group objects in the category of *coarse spaces*, as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarse_structure)*. This is an additive category.

Note that every abelian locally compact topological group $G$ could be seen as a coarse group, by setting $E\subset G\times G$ to be controlled iff
$\{x-y\mid (x,y)\in E\}$ is precompact in $G$.

One sees easily that the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an isomorphism in $\text{ACG}$, thus we get a natural isomorphism of rings, $\text{End}_\text{ACG}(\mathbb{Z})\simeq \text{End}_\text{ACG}(\mathbb{R})$.

One also sees easily that the natural map of rings
$\mathbb{R} \simeq \text{End}_\text{AG}(\mathbb{R}) \to \text{End}_\text{ACG}(\mathbb{R})$ is an isomorphism (here $\text{AG}$ stands for Abelian Groups).

One gets a natural ring isomorphism $\mathbb{R} \simeq \text{End}_\text{ACG}(\mathbb{Z})$ by composing the above maps.
Further, Hom sets in the category of abelain coarse groups could be naturally topologized, and this is an isomorphism of topological rings.

Similarly, one gets that $\mathbb{Q}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}$ is an isomorphism in $\text{ACG}$ (here $\mathbb{A}$ stands for the rational adels) and concludes an
isomorphism of topological rings
$\mathbb{A}\simeq \text{End}_\text{ACG}(\mathbb{Q})$.

---

$*$ For our discussion here, we take for morphisms in the category of coarse spaces classes of controlled maps,
that is maps $f:X\to Y$ such that for every controlled $E\subset X\times X$, $f\times f(E)\subset Y\times Y$ is controlled, and $f\sim g:X\to Y$ if $f\times g(X\times X)$ is bounded in $Y$.
We note that the category thus obtained has products, so talking about group objects makes sense.

Comment: The 2018 bachelor's thesis in Leiden by Tessa Hermans gives a construction in this way for $\mathbf R$, $\mathbf Q_p$, and the adele ring of $\mathbf Q$: see  https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/bachelor/2017-2018/hermans-bscthesis.pdf

Comment: @KConrad, thanks for the reference. This seems an excellent bachelor's thesis! Indeed, it puts things in a categorical framework. However, this framework is slightly different then the one I suggest. In particular, it does not allow isomorphisms such as $\mathbb{Z}\simeq\mathbb{R}$, which in my mind demystify the picture.

Comment: Let me illustrate further by discussing the $p$-adics. 
It is easy to see that $\text{End}(\mathbb{Q}_p)\simeq \mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p\simeq \mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p \simeq \mathbb{Z}[1/p]/\mathbb{Z}$.
We thus construct the $p$-adics as $\text{End}(\mathbb{Z}[1/p]/\mathbb{Z})$.